# How to distribute same sized <div>s inside a parent <div> equally?

Tags: html, css

Here is my current HTML:

```
<div style="height:50px; width:1200px">

    <div tabindex="0" class="banner" onclick="location.href='Home.html'">
        Link1
    </div>

    <div tabindex="0" class="banner" onclick="location.href='Page 1.html'">             
        Link2
    </div>

    <div tabindex="0" class="banner" onclick="location.href='Page 2.html'">
        Link3
    </div>

    <div tabindex="0" class="banner" onclick="location.href='Page 3.html'">
        Link4
    </div>

</div>
```

And my current CSS:

```
.banner {
    background: orange;
    color: aqua;
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size: x-large;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

How do I set the orphan s to be equally spaced along the parent  using css? I have set each of the orphan s to be 24% of the parent, as when they were set to 25%, the furthest right dropped beneath (I presume due to borders taking up additional space). I am using percentages of the parent as when zoomed out, the furthest right  dropped beneath, but this was the only part of the webpage that changed due to zooming. I tried setting the margins of the orphans to auto, but this didn't work, and changing the float caused them to decrease in width.

Update: I realised that I should have asked for the two s on either end of the parent  to be at the very end of it, whilst the two inner s are equally spaced in the remaining gap.

Fixed: It was the borders on the orphan s adding to the width. I opted for taking away the borders, as the webpage looked better without them anyway.

Comment: Try `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: When I put that into the css of .banner, I got a message saying it's not supported by the current schema, and when previewed, nothing changed.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Um.. I've checked it in Chrome - I'll preview it in others now.

Comment: Oh, and it's microsoft expressions web that is saying it's not supported.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing border-box is supported in all major browsers.

Comment: Hmm... seems weird. So I should put box-sizing into the css of .banner?

Comment: Here's the very basics of its structure: http://jsfiddle.net/Gy8Ld/

Comment: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/

Comment: This is one option for what it could look like : http://jsfiddle.net/Gy8Ld/1/ Alternatively, I could set the orphan <div>s to automatically expand to take up the entire width of the parent equally, but I don't know how.

Comment: (The code used in the jsfiddle is just a quick write-up; it wouldn't work when the zoom is changed). And sorry I really don't have time to change my site to a flexbox design - I need to complete it today preferably.

Answer (score 0):

Css Code:

```
 .banner {
        background: orange;
        color: aqua;
        box-sizing: border-box;/*Added New Style*/
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        height: 50px;
        vertical-align: top;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Garamond;
        font-size: x-large;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height:50px;
        cursor:pointer;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
```

Your banner having `1px border` that's why there were not fitting.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/tbajr/)</kbd>